# How to convert const std::filesystem::directory_entry& to string in c++

Tags: c++, directory, filesystems, c++17

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>   
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    string path = "/logs";
    string str = "";
    for (const auto& file : directory_iterator(path))
    {
        // want to convert file into a string str
    }
}
```

I can just `cout << file` and it serves the purpose of printing the path like a string onto the console but I want to convert the `const std::filesystem::directory_entry` into a string for later manipulation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The `directory_iterator` iteraterates over a set of `directory_entry`, which has a `path()` member. The `path` in turn is convertible to `std::string`.

So to get all the way

```
std::string name = file.path().string();
```